# Cannot open local sdf file in ignition gazebo

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Continuing Discussion from: https://community.gazebosim.org/t/cannot-open-local-sdf-file-in-ignition-gazebo/504

I am trying out the ignition gazebo citadel, and I am a bit confused on how this works compared to the classical gazebo.

I have a local `model.sdf` that I want to open in ignition gazebo. However, the application exists without any obvious errors. The output on the console is as the following.

```
ign gazebo ./model.sdf -v 5
[Msg] Ignition Gazebo Server v2.15.0
[Msg] Ignition Gazebo GUI    v2.15.0
[Msg] Loading SDF world file[/home/jaeyoung/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models/uneven_ground/./model.sdf].
[Dbg] [Application.cc:87] Initializing application.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:407] Create main window
[Dbg] [ign.cc:150] Shutting down ign-gazebo-server
[GUI] [Dbg] [SignalHandler.cc:141] Received signal[2].
[GUI] [Dbg] [SignalHandler.cc:141] Received signal[2].
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:130] Terminating application.
```

Version of ignition gazebo is:

```
$ ign gazebo --version
Ignition Gazebo, version 2.15.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2.0 License.
```

Update:
The sdf file I am trying to spawn is this one: https://github.com/PX4/sitl_gazebo/blob/master/models/uneven_ground/model.sdf

But also other models in the repo have the same result

---

### Update

@chapulina Thanks for the answer,

I created a sdf file following your suggestion, as the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
    <!-- Runs physics -->
    <plugin
    filename="libignition-gazebo-physics-system.so"
    name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>

    <!-- Broadcasts the server state to the GUI -->
    <plugin
    filename="libignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system.so"
    name="ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>

    <!-- Supports commands like spawning and teleporting entities -->
    <plugin
    filename="libignition-gazebo-user-commands-system.so"
    name="ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands">
    </plugin>
</sdf>
```

however it still fails to load anything

```
$ ign gazebo ./ignition.world -v 5
[Msg] Ignition Gazebo Server v2.15.0
[Msg] Ignition Gazebo GUI    v2.15.0
[Msg] Loading SDF world file[/home/jaeyoung/src/Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo/worlds/./ignition.world].
[Dbg] [Application.cc:87] Initializing application.
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:407] Create main window
[Dbg] [ign.cc:150] Shutting down ign-gazebo-server
[GUI] [Dbg] [ign.cc:230] GUI requesting list of world names. The server may be busy downloading resources. Please be patient.
[GUI] [Dbg] [SignalHandler.cc:141] Received signal[2].
[GUI] [Dbg] [SignalHandler.cc:141] Received signal[2].
[GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:130] Terminating application.
```

### Update2

@chapulina Although adding the default world plugins stopped the ign client from crashing, I still cannot spawn models such as https://github.com/PX4/sitl_gazebo/tree/master/models/plane into the world. And does the model always need to be predefined inside the world sdf file? Is it possible to spawn vehicles in a already existing world?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24586/cannot-open-local-sdf-file-in-ignition-gazebo/) by [Jaeyoung-Lim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24627/jaeyoung-lim/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-03-17**:
I moved the other answer you created to an update to the question. You will need to add the  tags to the SDF world file you're loading, inside the `<world>` tag.

**Comment by [Jaeyoung-Lim](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24627/jaeyoung-lim/) on 2020-03-18**:
Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

While on Gazebo-classic all features are enabled at all times, even if users don't need them, on Ignition users can turn on only the features they need.

Right now, all necessary features must be explicitly enabled on the SDF file. We're already [working](https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/pull-requests/537/) on a way for Ignition to load a few default plugins if the user doesn't specify any, but this will only be available in the upcoming minor releases.

Until then, you should include all world plugins that you need, like `Physics` and `SceneBroadcaster`. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/src/dd4ff2a4c1112a8727c12a2e927e87ca64392611/examples/worlds/empty.sdf#lines-60)'s a good list to start with:

```
<!-- Runs physics -->
<plugin
  filename="libignition-gazebo-physics-system.so"
  name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics">
</plugin>

<!-- Broadcasts the server state to the GUI -->
<plugin
  filename="libignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system.so"
  name="ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
</plugin>

<!-- Supports commands like spawning and teleporting entities -->
<plugin
  filename="libignition-gazebo-user-commands-system.so"
  name="ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands">
</plugin>
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aserbremen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/151257/aserbremen/) on 2023-03-08**:
The links are broken